# Get the Component name from Changeset

Tags: java, rtc, jazz

I have a Component associated to changeset.

Now I need to get the Component name from the changeset not the .getItemId()

I have managed to fetch the IComponentHandle object.
I have been searching for a way to get the Component name from IComponentHandle. ... Can you help me into that !

```
  IComponentHandle component = changeSet.getComponent();
  IConfiguration configuration = workspaceConnection.configuration(component);
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have:

```
IProgressMonitor monitor;
ITeamRepository repository;
```

You can use:

```
IComponentHandle componentHandle= changeSet.getComponent();

IComponent component = (IComponent) repository.itemManager().fetchCompleteItem(componentHandle, IItemManager.DEFAULT, monitor);
```

To get the component and use:

```
component.getName()
```